# Basis mod_rewrite rule results in 500 internal server error

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this very basic rewrite rule, no matter what I try, results in an Error 500.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^folder/(.*) /folder/index.php?Alias=$1 [L]
```

My httpd.conf file has the following content: (which seems OK to me)

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
    Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
   <IfModule mod_suphp.c>
        suPHP_Engine On
        suPHP_UserGroup webapps webapps
    SetEnv PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR
   </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

Any suggestions on what might be going wrong? I've also tried to add `$` at the end of my rewrite rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rewrite engine will loop repeatedly, until the URI stops changing, or the internal redirect limit is reached which causes the 500 error to be thrown. Your rule's target URI `/folder/index.php` will get thrown back into the rewrite engine and your same rule's regex matches it, `^folder/(.*)`. So you'll need to add some kind of condition to prevent the loop.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folder/index\.php
RewriteRule ^folder/(.*) /folder/index.php?Alias=$1 [L]
```

This is simple, it simply won't apply the rule if it already starts with `/folder/index\.php`. You can also try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^folder/(.*) /folder/index.php?Alias=$1 [L]
```

This is a little less restrictive of a condition. It only applies the rule if the requested URI doesn't map to an existing file or directory. This assumes that when you try to go to `/folder/blahblah` there *isn't* a directory or file `blahblah` and that you want to route it through your index.php.

Comment: I totally overlooked the loop situation, kinda staring blind to my cursor thinking "why don't you just do as you're told." (the .htaccess, left confused and telling me it was doing what it was told ;)) Thanks. +1 and accepted.